# Applying PDA transitions over a list of input strings in haskell

Tags: haskell, pushdown-automaton

I'm trying to implement a PDA in Haskell based on my lecturer's notes, she has described the general process to us and left the actual function implementation up to us. I feel like I have the majority of it working bar one little bug in the `nextsteps` function.

The rules of the PDA are as follows:

`[((1,"a",""),(1,"a")),((1,"b",""),(1,"b")),((1,"a",""),(2,"")),((1,"b",""),(2,"")),((1,"",""),(2,"")),((2,"a","a"),(2,"")),((2,"b","b"),(2,""))]`

```
    run :: PDA -> String -> Result
run _ "" = Reject
run (state,finalState,rules) str = findpath [(state,str,""(state,finalState,rules) 
data Result = Accept | Reject deriving Show

type PDA = (Int,[Int],[Transition])


-- Takes in the start state, the current value read by the input string, the current stack and the new state along with the change to the stack
-- ((1,"a",""),(1,"a"))
type Transition = ((Int, String, String),(Int,String))

-- contains the current state, current input string and current state of the stack
--    (1,"abba","ba")
type Configuration = (Int, String, String)

--if the list of configurations isnt accepted, apply the PDA transitions to it and try again
findpath :: [Configuration] -> PDA -> Result
findpath [] pda = Reject 
findpath (h:t) (a,b,c) = if accept (h:t) b == True then Accept else findpath (nextsteps (h:t) c) (a,b,c) 

accept' :: Configuration -> [Int] -> Bool
accept' config [] = False
accept' (x,y,z) [a] = if x == a  && y == "" && z == "" then True else False

accept:: [Configuration] -> [Int] -> Bool
accept [] _ = False
accept _ [] = False
accept (h:t) finalState = if accept' h finalState then True else accept t finalState


-- apply a given transition to a configuration based on the values in the configuration and transition
step :: Configuration -> Transition -> [Configuration]
step (a,b,"")((d,"",""),(g,"")) = if a == d then [(g,b,"")] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"")((d,"",""),(g,h)) = if a == d then [(g,bs,[b])] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,"",f),(g,"")) = if a == d then [(g,(b:bs),f)] else []   
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,"",f),(g,h)) = if a == d then [(g,(b:bs),h)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,[e],""),(g,"")) = if a == d && b == e then [(g,bs,"")] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,[e],""),(g,h)) = if a == d && b == e then [(g,bs,[b])] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,[e],f),(g,"")) = if a == d && b == e then [(g,bs,"")] else []
step (a,(b:bs),"") ((d,[e],f),(g,h)) = if a == d && b == e then  [] else []
step (a,b,c) ((d,"",""),(g,"")) = if a == d then [(g,b,c)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),c) ((d,"",""),(g,h))  = if a == d then  [(g,bs,c)] else []
step (a,b,(c:cs))((d,"",[f]),(g,"")) = if a == d && c == f then [(g,b,cs)] else []
step (a,b,(c:cs)) ((d,"",[f]),(g,h)) = if a == d && c == f then [(g,b,cs++h)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),c) ((d,[e],""),(g,"")) = if a == d then [(g,bs,c)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),c) ((d,[e],""),(g,h)) = if a == d && b == e then [(g,bs,[b]++c)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),(c:cs)) ((d,[e],[f]),(g,""))= if a == d && b == e && c == f then [(g,bs,cs)] else []
step (a,(b:bs),(c:cs)) ((d,[e],[f]),(g,h)) = if a == d && b == e && c == f then [(g,bs,cs++h)] else []

-- apply the entire ruleset of the PDA over one configuration and return a list of the results
steps :: Configuration -> [Transition] -> [Configuration] 
steps config [] = []
steps (a,b,c) (h:t) = if b /= "" then step (a,b,c) h ++ steps (a,b,c) t else []


-- take in a list of configurations and apply the entire rulest over each configuration and return a list of results
nextsteps :: [Configuration] -> [Transition] -> [Configuration]
nextsteps config [] = []
nextsteps (h : t) rules =  steps h rules ++ nextsteps t rules
```

The program works for certain strings and not others, I'm certain its to do with my nextsteps function. In my lecturer's notes she gives the example
`nextsteps [(1,"bbabba","a"),(2,"abbabba",""),(2,"bbabba","") rules = [(1,"babba","ba"),(2,"babba","a"),(2,"bbabba","a")]`

However, when I call the function on the exact same inputs I get `[(1,"babba","ba"),(2,"babba","a"),(2,"babba","a"),(2,"bbabba","a")]`.

I'm not sure where this extra duplicate value is coming from and is the main reason why strings that shouldn't be excepted are getting accepted. I have tried removing the tail of the configurations list and only applying the steps function to the head of the list, and that will make sure any list that shouldn't be accepted is `Rejected`, but also `Rejected` inputs that should be `Accepted`.

Comment: Why not add some types and make it more general. Make it so the types force you to only be able to represent valid configurations or transitions. E.g `data Transition state letter symbol =  Trans (state, Maybe letter, symbol) (state,  [symbol])`

Comment: Isn't that what `type Transition = ((Int, String, String),(Int,String))` is for? Apologies, I'm new to Haskell and PDA's.

Comment: The point is that if you write your function to be general then you are forced to not accidentally mix up stack symbols and word symbols. You are also forced to e.g. not have more than one letter on the LHS. Questions: is your automata meant to be deterministic? What do you intend by a `Transition` like `((a,b,""),...)`? Does the empty string mean bottom of the stack?

Comment: Your definition of `nextsteps` looks wrong. Specifically when you reach the end of the list of configurations, you will have a pattern matching error.

Comment: The automata is non-deterministic, for the Transition `a = initial state, b = current input read by the automata (a,b) and c is the current state of the stack, while "" simply denotes an empty stack`. I dont get any pattern matching errors, it usually defaults to [(2,"","")] or []. This changes though depending on wether I use `nextsteps (h : t) rules =  steps h rules ++ nextsteps t rules` or `nextsteps (h : t) rules =  steps h rules`